# Write reference to xsd/schema in output from XElement.Save()

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xelement

In C#, assume that I have an `XElement` (say `myXElement`) containing some XML structure. By calling

```
   myXElement.Save("/path/to/myOutput.xml");
```

the XML is written to a text file. However, I would like this textfile to include a reference to a (local) xsd-file (an XML schema). That is, I would like the output to look something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyElement
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MySchema.xsd">
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the root element, just add an attribute:

Example 1:

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement e = d.CreateElement("MyElement");
XmlAttribute a = d.CreateAttribute("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

a.Value = "MySchema.xsd";

d.AppendChild(e);
e.Attributes.Append(a);
```

Example 2:

```
XDocument d = new XDocument();
XElement e = new XElement("MyElement");
XAttribute a = new XAttribute(XName.Get("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"), "MySchema.xsd");

d.Add(e);
e.Add(a);
```

Comment: I am using XElement and XDocument, not XmlElement or XmlDocument, so it is not clear (for me) how to apply your code.

Comment: The "Example 2" for XElement doesn't use the `xsi` prefix. It uses a generated `p1` prefix instead. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76475528/1882616) using `XElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix` to get output with `xsi`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use XDocument instead of XElement as this contains methods for getting and setting the XML declaratuion etc
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This extends [Josh M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377138/1882616) to use the `xsi` prefix with `XElement` as requested. `XElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix` must be used; otherwise, `XElement` will assign its own prefix like `p1`.

```
XDocument d = new();
XElement e = new("MyElement");
XAttribute xsi = new(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
d.Add(e);
e.Add(xsi);
XAttribute noNs = new(e.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi")!.GetName("noNamespaceSchemaLocation"), "MySchema.xsd");
e.Add(noNs);
```

Calling `d.Save("MyDocument.xml");` produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MySchema.xsd" />
```